# How do I run a Google Apps Script From R/Python

Tags: python, r, google-apps-script

I have a workflow that is a combination of R (`googlesheets4`), Python (`xlwings`) and Google Appscripts.

Right now I am able to run the R and Python code together with the help of `reticulate`, however for the Google Appscripts, I need to run the code manually.

I have been exploring [`clasp`](https://github.com/google/clasp) but it doesn't seem to be desirable because of the various config issues that I have to troubleshoot along the way.

Are there any secure approaches for running Google AppScripts from R or Python?

I have seen the option to deploy an API executable but I have not seen how to set my headers appropriately.

Comment: Although I'm not sure whether I could correctly understand your expected result, for example, is this thread useful? https://stackoverflow.com/q/77256994