# Getting Internal error encountered when running Google APP script using GoogleAPI npm library

Tags: javascript, node.js, google-apps-script, google-drive-api, google-docs-api

I have a Google app script that takes a DOC ID as input and converts it into a PDF using the below code:

```
 var pdfFile = DriveApp.createFile(doc.getBlob().getAs('application/pdf'));
```

Now I am running the above-mentioned Google APP script from a node js server using googleapis npm library and I am executing in the below way

```
     try {
        const request = {
          scriptId: SCRIPT_ID,
          resource: {
            function: 'exportDocToPDFAndSaveToDrive', 
          },
          auth: client,
        };
        const response = await script.scripts.run(request);
        console.log(response.data);
      } catch (err) {
        console.log("Error in executing a google app's script", JSON.stringify(err));
      }
```

Now when running the the above code from a NODE JS Server I am getting the below error
`[{"message": "Internal error encountered.","domain": "global", "reason": "backendError"}]}`
I am performing authentication using a service account and I shared the script with the service account email.
I linked the Google App script and GCP project of that service account in Project settings section of Google Apps script.
What could be the reason for this issue and in API's and Services of the GCP project I enabled Google App script API.
i am using below scopes during authorisation

```
  'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive',
  'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.file',
  'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets',
  'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/documents',
  'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/documents.readonly',
  'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.readonly',
  'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/script.external_request',
```

Please help me with above query

Comment: About `I am performing authentication using a service account` in your question, I think that this might be the reason for your current issue. The official document says `Warning: The Apps Script API does not work with service accounts.`. [Ref](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/api/concepts) So, if you want to run Google Apps Script using the service account, it is required to use a workaround. In that case, is this thread useful for your situation? https://stackoverflow.com/q/77256994 This sample is for Python. But, the logic of this workaround can be also used with node.js.

Comment: I went through the workaround solution you mentioned so related to web apps url is it going to be generated when we clicked deploy or should we customise it anywhere and provide during deployment

Comment: Thank you for replying. I have to apologize for my poor English skill. Unfortunately, I'm not sure whether I could understand your reply. Is this information useful? https://gist.github.com/tanaikech/ebf92d8f427d02d53989d6c3464a9c43 You can use each Web Apps URL for each deployment. And, you can also use only one Web Apps URL even when the script is modified. If I misunderstood the question in your reply, I apologize.

Comment: I tried executing based on the workaround provided but I am getting ```The domain policies associated with the user are invalid or non existent```.Can you please help me how to resolve the issue

Comment: Thank you for replying. About `I tried executing based on the workaround provided but I am getting The domain policies associated with the user are invalid or non existent.Can you please help me how to resolve the issue`, I have to apologize for my poor English skill. Unfortunately, from your reply, I cannot understand your current situation. But, I would like to support you. So, can you provide the details flow for correctly replicating your current situation? By this, I would like to confirm it. I deeply apologize for my poor English skill again.

Comment: Per [the docs](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/api/reference/rest/v1/scripts/run): "The script project must be deployed for use with the Apps Script API."  Have you deployed the Apps Script project as an [API executable](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/api/how-tos/execute#step_2_deploy_the_script_as_an_api_executable)?